# Standard data types for email address, telephone number , first name, rixh text editor, etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, datatypes, table

I want to build a database for our system using Sql Server 2008 R2. but i need to know what are the best data types for storing these info:-

- Email address
- Telephone number with extension, such as +44 12345 ext 123
- First Name
- Rich Text editor. we have a field named "Position Role" or "Main duties", which stores a full description of each employee's roles.

Can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Comment: What does "best" mean? If I suggest first name as `nvarchar(50)` but you have users with longer first names, does that make it worse?

Comment: Whatever is suggested, make it larger....

Comment: @AaronBertrand i mean by best as standard format ?

Comment: What is the standard format of a telephone number or a first name? Do you only accept phone numbers from one country code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **E-mail address**: I go with `NVARCHAR(320)` - 64 characters for local part + `@` + 255 for domain name. You may also consider [normalizing the domain away](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2657/storing-email-addresses-more-efficiently-in-sql-server/), since it's pretty wasteful to store `hotmail.com` 500,000 times when a much smaller `INT` or even `SMALLINT` is probably capable (I don't know how many domains you plan to support). I used to be against `NVARCHAR` but the standard has [expanded to support Unicode characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531), so even though most mail servers in the world will reject them, better safe than sorry. Next will be to enforce validation - you can read [all you want to know about valid formats, and then some, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).
- **Telephone Number**: Probably some `varchar` in the 25-30 range (here you don't need Unicode support). Unless you know for sure you will only support phone numbers from certain geographical areas, then your choice is much simpler. What is "best" is hard for us to gauge - do you want perfect storage for the formats you support now, or more flexible storage in case you support more later or in case people are sloppy at entering form data and you still want to capture whatever they entered.
- **First name**: Completely subjective. Probably `nvarchar(50)` but I [agree with @kevinsky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86323/standard-data-types-for-email-address-telephone-number-first-name-rixh-text#comment154843_86323) - ask the business people what they think the longest first name is (or, if you have source data in another system, verify), then double it. Because I promise as soon as someone puts some artificial limit on the length, someone will come along and break the rule.
- **Role**: Again, this is pretty subjective. Is this supposed to be a paragraph of text, or an autobiography? You will need to decide if you want to allow some finite number of characters (say, `nvarchar(1000)`) or much larger than standard formats (e.g. `nvarchar(max)`, which supports up to 2GB of data per row). You should also take total row size into consideration - it may be easy to pick `nvarchar(4000)` but you will quickly exceed the row size and force some of that data to be stored inefficiently if people really use it. If a role is tied to a title and not a specific person, this should probably be stored elsewhere anyway.

Make sure your form fields are set to these max lengths, make sure any input is validated and sterilized, and make sure you use parameterized inputs to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am using asp.net mvc which automatically takes care for SQL injection attacks and i will also add server& client side validations for the data types. but regarding the telephone number i need to support number from multiple country codes,, so which data type best fit?

Comment: @johnG A varchar that fits the longest number you need to support.

Comment: what do u mean exactly ? can you adivce please ?

Comment: What I mean exactly is if you have a phone number like `+44 0123 4567` then you need at least a `varchar(13)`.

Comment: i checked the attributes on active directory seems that first-name can not exceed 29 characters and same apply to last name. for  the telephone it can not exceed 64 characters,, seems it is a good source to such info .. waht do u think ?

Comment: Yes, if these are to match AD then those seem like good guidelines. (But does this imply you're going to store AD information redundantly? Why not just pull it from AD? How will updates to SQL Server be replicated to AD and vice versa?)

Comment: I want this inside our HR system. where i define a table inside my system which got populated on daily basis using a sync job which will check for any updates  inside AD (such as user is added, deleted, his info was updated) and update them to the table . i need this because having AD users info inside a table will ease sorting, filtering, searching user info ...also i want to link users with their holiday records, etc by defining foreign keys. and i do not allow adding users from the HR system,, they need to be created inside the AD first... does this sound valid ?

Comment: @johnG Sure, I don't run your business or pay your salary or any of that, so if your managers are good with it, great. Just make sure they're aware that if you're only syncing once a day, then for any given 24 hour period the data could be wrong.

Comment: AD data is slow changing in all ways ,, and this approach is used widely. also i provide a way to sync manually. i think this is fine..

Comment: @johnG then why are you asking if I think it sounds valid?

Comment: because you asked the following ". (But does this imply you're going to store AD information redundantly? Why not just pull it from AD? How will updates to SQL Server be replicated to AD and vice versa?) "